# Can’t figure out whether a sequence of functions converges uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

The sequence in question is $ f_n(x)= 1 - \exp (- \frac{nx^2}{nx + 1})$, and the interval is [ 1/2 , 3 ] I tried finding the sup of the difference between this and the limit function, using the derivative, to no avail.

Comment: Hint: $\frac {nx^{2}} {nx+1} \to x$ uniformly on the given interval.

Comment: @geetha290krm hmmm i see, even if  i don’t see how that helps (i’m sure it does). does it have to do with the fact that $ 1-e^{-x}$ is continuous?

Comment: Apply MVT to $1-e^{-x}$.

Comment: Show sequence is monotone in $n$, and limit function is continuous ... "Dini's theorem".

Comment: @geetha290krm i don’t get it.. what does mvt have to do with it?

Comment: Alternatively (with geetha290krm's first hint), show that if $(g_n)\to g$ uniformly on an interval $I$ and $\phi$ is uniformly continuous on $I$, then $(f_n)=(\phi\circ g_n)$ converges uniformly on $I$ to $f = \phi\circ g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{(n+1)x^2}{(n+1)x+1} = 1+ \frac{1}{n^2 x+n x+n}\uparrow1,$$ from which we conclude that the sequence $f_n$ is monotone ($f_{n+1}\geqslant f_n$ for all $n$), with the pointwise limit $f(x):=1-e^{-x}$.

As $f_n$ is defined on the compact space $[1/2, 3]$ and $f$ is continuous, by Dini's theorem it follows that the convergence is uniform.